# How to add active class to the pagination in React

Tags: reactjs, class, pagination

I have a pagination component like this:

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const Pagination = ({ currentPage, postsPerPage, totalPosts, paginate }) => {
  const pageNumbers = [];
  for (let i = 1; i <= Math.ceil(totalPosts / postsPerPage); i++) {
    pageNumbers.push(i);
  }
  return (
    <nav>
      <ul className="pagination">
        <li class="page-item">
          <Link class="page-link" to={currentPage-1} onClick={() => paginate(currentPage-1)} aria-label="Previous">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
          </Link>
        </li>
        {pageNumbers.map((number) => (
          <li key={number} className="page-item">
            <Link
              onClick={() => paginate(number)}
              to={number}
              className="page-link"
            >
              {number}
            </Link>
          </li>
        ))}
        <li class="page-item">
          <Link class="page-link" to={currentPage+1} onClick={() => paginate(currentPage+1)} aria-label="Next">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
          </Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  );
};

export default Pagination;
```

So, what I want to do is when it is on page 5 for example, I want to add active class to that li so I can figure out on what page I am. Could you give me an advice about it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cann add calssName `active` for `currentPage` like this:

```
<Link
  className={`page-link ${currentPage === number ? "active" : ""}`}
>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Link, yiou can use NavLink which gives you the isActive property to add activeClassName to the page index in your pagination:

```
<NavLink to={`${yourLinkToPage}`} className={({isActive}) => `someClassName ${isAtive ? activeClassName : ""}`} >LinkName</NavLink>
```

and you can see the documentation also:

[verion 5](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/NavLink), [version 6](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/components/nav-link)